# Problem with with setting proxy variables in .bat file (Results differing outputs in cmd and batch)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, proxy, conda

**Describing the problem**

I am trying to create a conda environment from .yml file in a .bat file. Since I am doing this within my company, it is needed to configure proxy. When I do it in command window, the environment is successfully created. However, when in the .bat file, an exceptions occurs and conda provides an error report to be sent.

This .bat file I am composing is very needed, so **my questions are:**

> *Are there any import differences between running this process on batch and cmd that unable me from getting this from the .bat file? What do I need to do to run this process on .bat file?*

**Code examples to reproduce the problem:**

**1. On Command Window**

On cmd, if I run the following commands, I *can get my result*, which is creating the environment specific in the .yml file (samples only):

```
set https_proxy=https://username:password@proxy:port

conda env create -f environment-sample.yml
```

**2. On .bat file**

On .bat, running the file containing the following code, I get an error message, which will be presented below:

```
REM Using Delayed Expansion because this code will be inside an IF statement on .bat
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p login="Login: "
set /p password="Password: "
set https_proxy=https://!login!:!password!@proxy:port

conda env create -f environment.yml
```

**ERROR MESSAGE RETURNED:**

```
Collecting package metadata: failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
        conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 305, in get_connection
        proxy_url = parse_url(proxy)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\url.py", line 199, in parse_url
        raise LocationParseError(url)
    urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: lnx237in.sjk.emb:9090

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1002, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\cli\main.py", line 73, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\cli\main_create.py", line 106, in execute
        installer.install(prefix, pkg_specs, args, env)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\installers\conda.py", line 27, in install
        unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(prune=getattr(args, 'prune', False))
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 107, in solve_for_transaction
        force_remove, force_reinstall)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 145, in solve_for_diff
        force_remove)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 235, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 85, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 286, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 678, in _prepare
        self.subdirs, prepared_specs)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 213, in get_reduced_index
        new_records = query_all(spec)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 176, in query_all
        return tuple(concat(future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)))
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 93, in query
        self.load()
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 147, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 218, in _load
        mod_etag_headers.get('_mod'))
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 429, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
        timeout=timeout)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 546, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 414, in send
        raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: lnx237in.sjk.emb:9090

`$ C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env-script.py create -f environment.yml`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\lib\tools.jar
  CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=0
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\MFINACI
              HTTPS_PROXY=<set>
      MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared
                          Libraries\compiler\lib\mic
                     PATH=C:\Anaconda3\;C:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\
                          usr\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Anaconda3\bin
                          ;C:\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
                          ;C:\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Sc
                          ripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\VNI\imsl\fnl710\winin140x64\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
                          Files\Microsoft Shared\VSA\10.0\VsaEnv;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
                          Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\mpirt;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared
                          Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
                          Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\mpirt;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\compiler;C:\Orac
                          le\product\11.2.0\client_32\bin;C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_64\bin
                          ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
                          Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Win
                          dows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance
                          Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin;C:\Program Files\Tortoi
                          seSVN\bin;C:\Users\MFINACI\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
                          Code\bin;C:\Users\MFINACI\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
         PYTHONIOENCODING=1252
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
         SSF_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SecureLogin\lib\sapcrypto.dll
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : C:\Users\MFINACI\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\MFINACI\.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.7
    conda-build version : 3.10.5
         python version : 3.7.2.final.0
       base environment : C:\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\MFINACI\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\MFINACI\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\MFINACI\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\MFINACI\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.7 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.2 Windows/7 Windows/6.1.7601
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]:
```

**Attempts to understand the problem**

I checked if the variables are being correctly assigned and they are. I did that basically "echoing" the variables. The screen result I got commenting the first line of the code (REM @echo off) are (Changing full path to make it cleaner):

```
C:\Users\MFINACI>set /p login="Login: "
Login: userexample

C:\Users\MFINACI>echo !login!
userexample

C:\Users\MFINACI>set /p password="Password: "
Password: passwordexample

C:\Users\MFINACI>echo !password!
passwordexample

C:\Users\MFINACI>set https_proxy=https://!login!:!password!@lnx237in.sjk.emb:9090

C:\Users\MFINACI>echo !https_proxy!
https://userexample:passwordexample@lnx237in.sjk.emb:9090
```

Also tried to find similar problems at the community, however, none of them present the problem of getting the results successfully on cmd and not on .bat file. Could you please help me?

> **This is my first question here, I really tried not to ask a duplicate and respect the rules of the community. Sorry if I made
>   anything wrong.**

Comment: Also, what is the value put into `https_proxy` variable? You should see it unless you have used `@ECHO OFF`. Remove or comment out `ECHO OFF` to see what is actually happening.

Comment: The first thing you should do is to use the preferred syntax when setting your variables. Try `Set /P "login=Login: "`, `Set /P "password=Password: "` and `Set "https_proxy=https://!login!:!password!@proxy:port"`, then come back to us with your feeback based upon those changes. It seems as though the error is in the information you've not given us, i.e. `!login!`, `!password!` or `proxy:port`, _(you've not even shown the content of `HTTPS_PROXY` in your output)_. The most likely culprit for this type of error is you're using a `%` character, which in a batch file should be doubled to `%%`

Comment: Hello @lit and Compo, thank you for coming to support me! I removed any echo, to make it cleaner for you guys to see, sorry for hiding these partial results.

Comment: As I said above, I checked the variables, and the way I did that was actually "echoing" those and these checks printed exactly what I was expecting. I will update the "Attempts to understand the problem" part of my question with these information, as a matter of clarification for anyone that will get here. 

Thanks for the feedback! I will set the corrections @Compo suggested and will come back for updates!

Comment: Indeed, @Compo hints about the preferred syntax solved my problem! Thank you so much, solved my first question here! I got this miswritten syntax from a code sample I found when learning .bat commands! So sorry about that! Wouldn't you like to place this comment as a response? Although it is a very simple solution, I think many people are caught on these errors when learning. Thank you again! :)